# White list domain in PHP or Apache/Nginx server

Tags: php, ubuntu, plesk

I was implementing API (without JWT) where user login is not needed. So, I choose basic authentication but, now anyone can stole it from Network (tab browser) because credentials are available during sending the request.

After the lot of the research I think it's better to whitelist domains ( 75 total in my system ). I tried it in CodeIgniter 3 but I am not getting a way to get the domain name via referrer or origin.
Now, the last solution to white list the domains in server. I have Plesk with Ubuntu installation but I don't know what should be the best solution for whitelist the domains in server. Also, I never did this type of the work in server.

I hope I have explained the question better!

Comment: you have API which are going to be called from other server, is it right?

Comment: Yes, I have the open API'S which are available to our customers to access. But, I know all the domains who are using our API'S.

Comment: I doubt if they call the api from php server, you will not get domain.

Comment: Yes you are right. But, I can white list the domain in the server because I know all the domains of my clients.

Comment: Better you can provide a secret key to them and let them pass into header.

Comment: But, that can also be available to other users if they copy the request as curl from browser they will get everything including headers and everything will become open as of now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237025/discussion-between-jagad89-and-vikas-dhiman).

Comment: Any secret token will only be available to other users if they call your API from Javascript, not if they do a server-to-server call. If you require authentication, then you should tell them not to call it from JS but rather create some back-end proxy for the calls. That's not an uncommon requirement. Using things like "referrer" is very unreliable (not always present) and can be spoofed. If they make a server-to-server call, then you can whitelist their IP's instead of domains.

Comment: When you say “whitelist a domain”, your plan is to inspect the incoming request for the origin IP address and then use `gethostbyaddr` to find the PTR record(s) for it? Or are you going to take all of the known domains, can `gethostbyname` on each, take the subsequent array of IPs and see if the origin IP is in it? This would be much easier if you just give each origin a unique key to put in the header. If there’s a problem, that key can be revoked and a new one provided.